# Why is my Socket.io Express app just sending to the 'sender's' client?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to write a basic chat application with Node.js (Express), and Socket.io.  Everything 'seems' to be working, but my socket server seems to be only 'sending' the message back to the original sender.  Here is my socket code:

```
var client = io.listen(app);

client.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.send(data);
  });
});
```

And here is my client side code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('A client connected.');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        $('#messages').html('<p>' + message + '</p>' +  $('#messages').html());
        console.log(socket);

    });

    $('input').keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {   
            socket.send($('input').val());
            $('input').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `client.sockets.emit` instead of `socket.emit`. It will emit to every connected client (broadcast), using the socket object only sends to the specific client.

Comment: For some reason when I use client.sockets.send(data), it works as expected, thanks to your help! But client.sockets.emit(data) is not broadcasting anything..

Answer (score 0):

Server side, I think you want:

```
socket.broadcast.emit(data);
```

instead of:

```
socket.send(data);
```

See "Broadcasting Messages" at the bottom of the ["How to use" page](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). :)